# Работа AOS анимации внутри div, есть ли простой способ?

Tags: css, css-animation

Есть ли простое решение, чтобы анимация AOS работала внутри DIV? Например, есть DIV с заданными размерами и прокруткой, надо, чтобы анимация работала внутри него при прокрутке содержимого.

Comment: Кажется, такого решения нет...

Comment: Хорошо, а не очень сложный, чтобы можно было понять не профи в этом вопросе?